# Using an Interface as a Type in Android

Tags: java, android, interface, fragment

This is the oracle's example in "Using an Interface as a Type":

```
public Object findLargest(Object object1, Object object2) {
   Relatable obj1 = (Relatable)object1;
   Relatable obj2 = (Relatable)object2;
   if ((obj1).isLargerThan(obj2) > 0)
      return object1;
   else 
      return object2;
}
```

so everything makes sense, nice and clean! Then I saw this code for creating Fragments and cannot see the logic for this method:
`public void updateDetail()` 
The listener is exerting a method which is empty. can someone please clear this for me?

```
public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

  private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,
        container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        updateDetail();
      }
    });
    return view;
  }

  public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onRssItemSelected(String link);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
      listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
          + " must implemenet MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    listener = null;
  }


  public void updateDetail() {
    String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

    listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: The fragment you posted doesn't implement the interface. The activity it is contained in does, and that is where that method will be.

Comment: yes, but what is the relation of the overridden method in mainClass and this method in Fragment class? the interface instance still is implementing an empty nethod

Comment: An interface will never implement any methods. It only defines them. Somewhere there is an activity that says `implements OnItemSelectedListener` and that activity will have the method `onRssItemSelected` and it will have code inside. If this fragment is attached to such an activity, the activity becomes the listener and the fragment calls the method in the activity. It comes from `listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;` during `onAttach`.

Comment: so, we override the method let's say, in the `mainClass` to return some String in the fragment, then when we use the button and the `onClick` method, the overriden method (by the mainClass) will be override again with the new String. is that right or I'm missing something again?

Comment: Let me see if it makes sense like this: First, the fragment is added to an activity and that activity becomes the listener(it has the implementation of `onRssItemSelected`). Next, the button in the fragment is clicked and calls `updateDetail`(which is in the fragment). Next, that method calls `onRssItemSelected` in the activity(passing it a String). Lastly, the activity does whatever it does inside `onRssItemSelected`.